# Powershell - remove multiple lines of text based on static array?

Tags: arrays, powershell

EDIT: 19/12/13

I failed in appropriately defining the input which may have caused confusion, sorry about that. The input file is a IIS log which the formatting needs to stay intact. The fields look like this; "Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken"

A url GET will show something like this;

*2013-12-07 00:23:50 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX POST / code=5071 80 - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) http://blah.blah.com/?code=5071 200 0 64 3478*

The "code=5071" helps us identify a url, if we strip all of the other ones out we can run a stats utility and find out how many hits, etc where for that one code.

---

Right then, I'm a total newb when it comes to coding so feel free to ridicule. I'm trying to take a log file and strip out lines based on multiple variables, I thought I could create an array and that way there was only one file to edit should a number need to be removed or added. The input file is a simple log containing several fields to which one is a 'ID' so something like; ddmmyy  blah  blah  ID.  The ID is a ten digit number to which there are thirty-seven. The purpose is to read the log, strip out all of the non-matching ID's and then output the result to a new log file.

This code works fine but it appears I can only have approximately fourteen "-And" in before it stops

```
Get-Content .\combined.log | Where-Object{$_-NotMatch '10011250' -And $_-NotMatch '10005816' -And $_-NotMatch '5077'} |Set-Content combined1.log
```

I trolled the net and learned as much as I could handle on arrays but nothing seems to work and I know it's me and how I set it up. I thought something like this might work;

```
$a = @(10011250, 10005816, 14200712, 2418, 10005699, 5071, 10001040, 4814, 10025390, 4175, 10005940, 10000040, 10008181)
Get-Content .\combined.log | ForEach($i in $a) {Where-Object{$_-notcontains $a}}| Set-Content combined1.log
```

As you can tell this is not my area of expertise by a long shot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a CSV or similar character-delimited file?  Is the ID the very last token that appears on each line?

Comment: Sorry was 'off-line' there for a bit, yes the file is a tab delimited file (log file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each line ends in a whitespace character followed by the integer ID, you can use this:

```
$excludedIds = 10011250, 10005816, 14200712, 2418, 10005699, 5071, 10001040, `
    4814, 10025390, 4175, 10005940, 10000040, 10008181;
# Build a pattern from $excludedIds that matches one or more whitespace `
# characters followed by one of the above IDs followed by the end of the line
# Example: '\s+(10011250|10005816|14200712|...)$'
$excludedPattern = '\s+(' + ($excludedIds -join '|') + ')$';

Select-String -Path '.\combined.log' -Pattern $excludedPattern -NotMatch `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Line' `
    | Set-Content -Path 'combined1.log';
```

The [`Select-String` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849903.aspx) will return an instance of the [`MatchInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.aspx) for each line that does *not* have an excluded ID.  We use the [`Select-Object` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849895.aspx) to retrieve the [`Line` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.line.aspx), representing the original line of text, of each `MatchInfo`.

Note that I am specifically searching for an entire ID at the very end of the line.  If I did not do this, I might incorrectly match on one ID that is a substring of another.  That is, the following line...

```
161213 Field1 Field2 10915816
```

...is matched by the pattern `'915'` but not `'\s+915$'` (whitespace followed by the string `'915'` followed by the end of the line).  This is behavior I suggest you double-check in your original code because it's possible you'll be filtering out IDs that are partial but not exact matches, which may not be desirable.

If the second and third field of each line do not contain any whitespace and you need to do additional processing on each line beyond just filtering, this might work better for you:

```
$excludedIds = 10011250, 10005816, 14200712, 2418, 10005699, 5071, 10001040, `
    4814, 10025390, 4175, 10005940, 10000040, 10008181;
$records = Import-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header 'Date', 'Field1', 'Field2', 'ID' -Path '.\combined.log' `
    | Where-Object { $excludedIds -notcontains $_.ID; };
```

`$records` will then contain a filtered list of objects, each with a corresponding `Date`, `Field1`, `Field2`, and `ID` property.  Unfortunately, the original line of text is now lost, so you'll have to rebuild it yourself (or use whatever output format you want):

```
$records `
    | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Date) $($_.Field1) $($_.Field2) $($_.ID)"; } `
    | Set-Content -Path 'combined1.log';
```

Comment: Thanks everyone and apologies for not getting on-line sooner, I haven't tried any of the examples yet but if it helps here's some further info: The file in is a log file and the string being searched for is "code=10011250". The log is a IIS log, we're trying to filter out all lines except for ones that match that way stats can be pulled for the one url (url references end in "code=xxxxxxx". Make sense?

Comment: @Anokii These PowerShell solutions still apply, but you might also want to look into [Microsoft's LogParser utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) as well.  It allows SQL queries to be performed against many different types of input, including IIS logs.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/03/25/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries.aspx) for examples.

Comment: Never even seen "LogParser" before what a great find - thanks heaps BACON, up and running and got my data in a matter of minutes. Merry Christmas all...!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can test for more than one value in the same -match operation using alternation in your regex. Separate multiple values to match for with the pipe symbol (|).

```
Get-Content .\combined.log | Where-Object{$_-NotMatch '10011250|10005816'}
```

will filter out all the lines that match either 10011250 or 10005816.
Also, the -match operator will match against an entire array at once, and return the members that satisfy the condition.

Try this:

```
$a = @(10011250, 10005816, 14200712, 2418, 10005699, 5071, 10001040, 4814, 10025390, 4175, 10005940, 10000040, 10008181)

$regex = [regex]($a -join '|')

Get-Content .\combined.log -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach {$_ -notmatch $regex | Add-Content combined1.log}
```

for BACON:

```
$lines = (
'Line containing 10011250',
'Line containing 10005816',
'Line containing 10011250',
'Line containing 10915816'
 )

$lines -notmatch '10011250|10005816'

Line containing 10915816
```

Comment: I believe you meant `'(10011250)|(10005816)'` as the first regex pattern.  Also, the problem with using regular expressions for this they will match integer substrings, too.  For example, your code above would (incorrectly) filter out IDs `'12418'`, `'24181'`, `'124181'`, etc. because they all match the pattern `'2418'`.  You need to make sure you're matching the entire string of digits.

Comment: No, I meant what I posted.  The parens aren't necessary in this application.  I'm assuming possible substring matching isn't a problem with this data, since the OP says his original solution worked, other than not being able to stack enough -and conditions in the same clause.

Comment: I would bet the author says his code "worked" because it filtered out IDs he expected it to filter out, but didn't test enough to see it will also filter out IDs he doesn't expect to be filtered.  Regarding your edit, if you change the last line to `$lines -notmatch '10011250|10005816|915'` notice that it now filters out `'10915816'`, too, because it matches the substring.  I don't think it's correct for `'915'` and `'10915816'` to be treated as the same ID.

Comment: I have to trust the OP on this.  The first rule of regex is "know your data", and right now he's the only one that does.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate it.

- Get the file contents
- Check every line against every item in the array
- If it passes every single item, add it to a new array
- Output the new array to file

---

## Without Console Output

```
$array = @(10011250, 10005816, 14200712, 2418, 10005699, 5071, 10001040, 4814, 10025390, 4175, 

10005940, 10000040, 10008181)

$file = ".\test.txt"
$log = Get-Content $file

ForEach ($line in $log) {
    ForEach ($item in $array) {
        if ($line -match "\b$($item)\b") {
            $good_lines += @($line)
        }
    }
}

$good_lines | Set-content ".\Combined1.log"
```

## With Console Output

```
$array = @(10011250, 10005816, 14200712, 2418, 10005699, 5071, 10001040, 4814, 10025390, 4175, 

10005940, 10000040, 10008181)

$file = ".\test.txt"
$log = Get-Content $file

Write-Host "`n`n-- FILE LOADED: $((Get-Item $file).fullname)" -ForegroundColor "White"

ForEach ($line in $log) {
Write-Host "`n-- READING LINE: $line" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    ForEach ($item in $array) {
        sleep -milliseconds 100
        Write-Host "-- COMPARING: $item ..." -nonewline -ForegroundColor "Cyan"
        if ($line -match "\b$($item)\b") {
            Write-Host "MATCH" -ForegroundColor "Green"
            $good_lines += @($line)
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "NO MATCH" -ForegroundColor "Red"
        }
    }
}

$good_lines | Set-content ".\Combined1.log"
```

Comment: Nope - output file "Combined1.log" is empty.

Comment: Oops... I was adding the array to the line, instead of the other way around :D edited now...